# Ethernet Networking technology

Tags: ethernet

Why does ethernet support only a maximum of 1024 nodes ?

Comment: What are you talking about?

Answer (score 8):

In a half-duplex Ethernet, a collision domain has an theoretical limit of 1024 nodes. This restriction was imposed by the back-off algorithm used that had a maximum 1024 time slots, where if there were more nodes than that that were simultaneously accessing the system, the collision might never be resolved.

Comment: This does not apply anymore on switched Ethernet networks, does it?

Comment: @grawity That is correct.  It only applied to 10-BaseT (coaxial) and Hub based networking topologies.  Anything where two devices would be trying to write to the same physical piece of copper. A hub is just seen as a join in the copper and is invisible to the network, whereas a switch separates the network into one point-to-point connection for each port.

Comment: @MattJenkins: 10BaseT (twisted pair) and coaxial (10Base2) were two different things (physically, but not topologically).

Comment: @Dennis Course they were... Silly me.  It's so long ago I can barely remember them ;)  I meant 10-Base2.